# How to change background color of default button without losing drop shadow and curved edge?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have tried many methods and failed to maintain the beautiful drop shadow of the default button.

I have

1. Changed the colorAccent color but it affects other widgets like rating bar
2. Set the background as color or image but that resulted in a flat button

Both the above methods didn't work for me...

Comment: share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Don't ask half question, If you are mentioning implement word  then please post what you implemented in question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

or

```
Button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

or

```
Button.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
```

then Set **elevation** for the button, otherwis use **material button**

Comment: just to add, it is better to get the color value with ContextCompat.
ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark)